# Base Href vs. .htaccess RewriteBase

Tags: url-rewriting, stylesheet, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Normally I use

```
<base href="http://domain.com/" /><!--[if ie]></base><![endif]-->
```

I haven't tried much with RewriteBase, I normally get confused and keep changing it till it works. Which method would be best, I obviously find  the best solution because the links stay the same so that no links are broken most of the time when attaching a css file, e.g.

> http://domain.com/css/main.css

It just always stay the same when accessing to sub-directories. Although, when I don't use the  tag, and I access to a sub directory, it breaks the css links when I use

```
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

As my PHP documents would include the header,

```
<?php include("include/global_header.php"); ?>
```

If I do that without the  I would have to use:

```
<link href="../css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Which can break when accessing to a sub-directory.

So... does the RewriteBase work the same as the ?

Your thoughts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basehref works at the HTML level on rendering of the webpage

RewriteBase is in the .htaccess file which is processed by Apache before the HTML is rendered.

As a result they perform different functions and cannot be comapared

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you just compared them. I still think it's an open question as to whether they perform the same function, despite the fact that they do it at different times in the page lifecycle. Voted up though, for pointing out the fundamental difference.